# select query returning more rows than the parameter passed

Tags: c#, select

earlier i tried this one

```
string query =  "SELECT TOP " + TraineesPerBlock + 
               @"         * 
                   FROM TraineeDetail 
                  WHERE SUBBR = '0' 
                 ORDER BY MAXM DESC" ;
```

In traineesPerBlock when value was passesd 69 it is giving 110 record, i should give 69 only.. MAXM is a double field, also there are records having same MAXM value.
Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure that the value passed is `69`, put a break point and confirm.

Comment: Can you tell me what type `TraineesPerBlock` is?

Comment: Just putting this here as well: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon

Comment: TraineePerBlock is an integer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I’d try to find out whether the trouble because of development environment or database.
Execute the script in the DBMS shell, replace TraineesPerBlock to numbers 69,70.
Execute the same operation in the studio.
Also, if TraineesPerBlock is int, try to cast it to string explicit.

Comment: This should be a comment really.  Casting the int to string will change nothing as the + operator here will perform ToString on the int internally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing hex and decimal?.

0x69 (hex) is awfully close to 105 (decimal), which is the number you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

> The top directive doesn't return the top n items, as one is easily led
>   to believe. Instead it returns at least n distinct items determined by
>   the ordering of the result.
>   Quoted From:
>   [Access SQL using TOP 5 returning more than 5 results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887787/access-sql-using-top-5-returning-more-than-5-results)