# MS Access SQL, SELECT last five highest values in a column

Tags: c#, ms-access

MS Access SQL, SELECT last five highest values in a column

For example I have table named games, I want top five games with highest likes.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
select top 5 *
from games
order by likes desc, id desc
```

I have added a "tie-breaker" to the order by clause to prevent access returning more than 5 records, i.e. the primary key.

Thanks to @Fionnuala for pointing out this issue with Access. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887787/access-sql-using-top-5-returning-more-than-5-results)

Comment: Top 5 will not necessarily return 5 records. All matched records will be returned. There are ways around if only 5 records are required.

Comment: @Fionnuala please explain.

Comment: If ten records in the sort column `likes` have top 5 values, 10 records will be returned.

Comment: @Fionnuala I did not know that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887787/access-sql-using-top-5-returning-more-than-5-results

Comment: Ansi 92 may not be the best idea, depending where you are in development. You can sort on two fields / columns to get a return of 5 rows, eg `order by likes, uniqueid desc`

Comment: @Fionnuala yes, the "tie-breaker" - makes sense. Thanks for the info.